# Starting a 2013 Workflow inside of another 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that I created using the 2013 platform on SharePoint Designer. It was suggested to be to create another workflow to perform email notifications and add it in to check a field to see if it is filled.

I have only used the interop bridge to run a 2010 workflow on the 2013 platform and this was successful.
When I go to insert the 2013 workflow, I add the action "Start a List Workflow" and the only option I get is for 2010. (See image)

[image: Start a List Workflow]

Am I missing a component or is it possible to run a 2013 workflow within another 2013 workflow???

I am using SharePoint Online, so the Workflow Manager should already be configured.

(Added snippet of current parallel block with "on change" action)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "Start a List Workflow" and "Start a Site Workflow" is specific to the SharePoint 2010 engine, not SharePoint 2013. Take a look here: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform

If you need to trigger another SharePoint 2013 workflow, I suggest you have another workflow tied to "On Change" and have that workflow look for a specific column that the first workflow updates (and is possibly hidden from the user).

Comment: That's what I was thinking, so thanks for confirming it. I have added a screen capture of one part of my workflow where I use a parallel block with a "wait for change in field". The email notification part would need to check to see if the field was completed after a couple of days, and if not, send an email. The current parallel block simply looks to see if it is "Approved" or "Rejected" and then proceeds from there.

Comment: Is that a different question?

Comment: Maybe. LOL. I'm trying not to confuse myself, much less you.
I guess I was saying and showing you what I did above to show you that the workflow is already waiting for a change in the item. I want the email notification to only happen if the field is left unanswered 5 days after its assigned. But I don't want it to totally hold up the workflow. Does that make sense? I'm trying to figure out if this is doable.

Comment: Add another Step that uses the action Pause until 5 days

Comment: I'm not trying to sound like a broken record, but won't that hold up the whole workflow for 5 days?
I want the workflow to be able to still advance for those people who go ahead and approve/reject.

Comment: not if it's running in parallel with the 2 steps, but since it's not approved or rejected, you will have to handle what to do after a 5 day unanswered mark.